# can I put 1600MHz memory in a late 2011 macbook pro?

Tags: memory, macbook

I want to update my memory from 4GB 1333MHz to 8GB 1600MHz, Ive read that it is possible but nothing concrete so I ask this again and hope someone with knowledge can answer.

The thing is that the price difference between 1600MHz and the 1333MHz is 6 USD thats why I ask.
Also lets say I buy the 1600 and my computer downclocks it, is it bad for my device?

Thank you for all the advice.

Comment: In a normal situation faster memory would simple be downclocked to the supported speed.  Since we are dealing with an Apple product it could reject the faster memory.  I suggest you just purchase the supported memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we speak of "1600MHz memory", we mean memory with a maximum rated speed of 1600MHz. It will run just fine at a lower speed. In fact, typically it will run *faster* and *cooler* than memory rated for the lower speed.

It is possible, though I haven't heard of this happening in many years, for the BIOS to refuse to accept the memory.

Comment: Oke so my interpretation is that it would be wiser to buy the 1600MHz even if my device might not reach that speed?

Comment: I generally recommend that all other things being equal, buy the exact memory to reduce the chances of an incompatibility. If you can find faster memory with guaranteed compatibility, then take it for sure. Otherwise, it's a judgment call. If you're going to have more than one memory stick though, try to match them as closely as possible.

Comment: thank you David, I will bargain with the reseller to let me try the memory and see if it works. 2 identical 4GB ram memory... Sorry to have to bother you one last time David, but would you recommend any manufacture? I was thinking of buying these (DDR3 1600 8GB 2x4GB CL9 - Corsair XMS3 Vengeance) but I dont know which manufactors are good and which are not

Answer (score 0):

For your specific model (and this is universal to all Late-2011 MacBooks), the memory bus runs at up to 1333MHz. If you purchase 1600MHz RAM, it will only be able to run at 1333MHz, which means you would be effectively wasting your money.

So to answer your second question, it won't be bad for your device, but it will be bad for your wallet.

Source: [Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1270#link1)